# what is a string literal surrounded with @ means in C++

Tags: c++, cmake

I came across this in a source code:
`#define DEFAULT_PATHNAME   "@SDK_DEFAULT_PATHNAME@"`

what does the `@` symbol denotes in this case ?

**Edit**:
Camke was used to generate this project.
This value is used as a path to a file

Comment: It doesn't have any special meaning by itself.   It's just a character in the string.  There's probably some interpolation code elsewhere in the code base that replaces identifiers of the form `@key@` with values from some dictionary.

Comment: that value is used as a path to a file for the program to open, when removing the `@` the program broke

Comment: IIRC this could have some special meaning in CMake text replacement.

Comment: @juanchopanza, the make file was generated using Cmake

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CMake has this wonderful command [`configure_file`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command%3aconfigure_file) which allows your build system to generate a file used in the build where the content (*i.e.* value) of the variable `SDK_DEFAULT_PATHNAME` will be put in the location  of `@SDK_DEFAULT_PATHNAME@` in the "configured file".

Comment: @Angew Request fulfiled :) ... (I have the link to CMake docs for some time in my bookmarks... obviously I need to update it :) )

Comment: SO has this wonderful user @fritzone who posts very nicely worded answers.

Answer (score 1):

In this case it's part of the string, nothing special.

On Windows for example, you could have the following string:

```
#define DEFAULT_PATHNAME "%PATH_TO_SDK%"
```

with the `%` character playing the same role. In C++ and in strings in general, it has no meaning (unlike `\` which is used to escape characters).

EDIT:
To clarify, esp. with regards to your comment:

> that value is used as a path to a file for the program to open, when removing the @ the program broke

The operating system may need to read this character, as I mentioned it with the `%` example on Windows, to consider the path as something to look up in the environment variables for example. Once again, it has no special meaning in C++ or strings in general, but may have for other programs.

Comment: exactly, I guess it is something related to OS like an evn. variable look up or something